# Connecting to two different databases with PouchDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to connect and sync to two different databases with PouchDB in my App and CouchDB on the server. I can connect to one but the second connection doesn't work as it should.

My code looks like this:

```js
    this._DB = new PouchDB('userdata');
let options = {
        live: true,   
        retry: true,  
        continuous: true
      };

this._syncHandler = this._DB.sync(remoteDB, options);

this._DB2 = new PouchDB('beer');
this._DB2.sync('localhost:5984/beer', options);
this._DB2.allDocs({})
        .then((doc)=> {
          console.log('****** TEST: doc = ' + JSON.stringify(doc));
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
          console.log('****** TEST: err = ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
```

When I run this code the console log lists the contents of the 'userdata' database and not the 'beer' database. This is odd and not what is intended.

Comment: Do you get an err?

Comment: No err that is the odd thing. The new PouchDB and the sync seem to work ok and the console log shows the TEST: doc output but the content of the doc is the content of the 'userdata' database and not the 'beer' database which is very odd.

Comment: In your sync, try adding `http://`. Found https://pouchdb.com/api.html#sync

Comment: I tried the http but it made no difference still getting the contents of the other database.

Comment: Are you sure the `beer` db is not the same as the `userdata` db? Potentially synced on accident once?

Comment: Good suggestion but no they haven't synced. The beer db has one document the userdata db has 43 documents.

Comment: What is stored in your `remoteDB` variable?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of things wrong here.

For a start, you have to include the protocol in the URL for the remote DB, ie. you need `http://` in front of your `localhost...`.

Then also, the `sync` call doesn't block, so you'll be calling `allDocs` before the actual replication has completed.  If you try again a bit later you'll find that the docs will be there.